# AngularJS: Unable to make routes case insensitive

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am unable to make Angular (1.5) routes case insensitive. I've tried adding `caseInsensitiveMatch: true` to the route configs, but my app still won't load unless I use the proper case. I want to make the routes case insensitive. Here's what my route config looks like:

```
module SoftwareRegistration {
    export class Routes {
        static $inject = ["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider"];
        static configureRoutes($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: true
            });

            $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
            $routeProvider
                .when("/",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.ListOrdersController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/listOrders.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Orders",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.ListOrdersController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/listOrders.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Orders/MyOrders",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.ListOrdersController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/listOrders.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Orders/Create",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.CreateOrderController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/createOrder.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Orders/PaymentInformation",
                {
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/paymentInformation.html",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Orders/:OrderId/AddRecipients",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.AddRecipientsController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/order/addRecipients.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .when("/Account/Login",
                {
                    controller: "SoftwareRegistration.LoginController",
                    templateUrl: "app/views/account/login.html",
                    controllerAs: "vm",
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/", caseInsensitiveMatch: true });
        }
    }
}
```

When I navigate to https://myserver.com/SoftwareRegistration it works fine. However, if I navigate to https://myserver.com/softwareregistration I get this error:

```
angular.js:12165 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Here's the source of angular.js:12165 :

```
function trimEmptyHash(url) {
  return url.replace(/(#.+)|#$/, '$1');
}
```

I should note, it works fine on my local (case insensitive) but doesn't work when I deploy to IIS

Comment: Hazarding a guess here, but try stripping the `caseInsensitiveMatch` property from both the root route (i.e. `"/"`) and the `otherwise` route catch. They shouldn't really have an affect there anyway since there's no text to match.

Comment: still not working... :(

Comment: how is the url passed to `trimEmptyHash`? Or maybe, what is the value of `url`?

Comment: i don't know, thats what i cant figure out... why its passing undefined instead of the url like it does on local, or when the case matches.

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well, it has to do with the base href value not matching.  See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4056) from more info.  Can you post what yours looks like?

Comment: OK, yes i just debugged and it is the same issue... `beginsWith()` is case sensitive, so they aren't matching exactly... now what to do about it? i'm not really satisfied with either of the workarounds mentioned. I'd rather not mod the source or force all of my URLs to redirect to lower on the server... any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a workaround that I am satisfied with from this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3703

I put this small script before angular is loaded to dynamically change the `<base>` to be whatever case the user typed in the URL

```
(function() {
    var base = document.querySelector( "base" );
    var normalized = RegExp( base.href, "i" ).exec( location.href );
    base.href = normalized ? normalized[ 0 ] : base.href;
}());
```

This may not be suitable in all situations. As mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4056 , this may "break" caching. However, I like this solution the best because I dont have to mod the source (or remember to change it every time I update), nor do I have to mess with any server settings (on IIS anyway).

Comment: This is a good solution, but it doesn't handle if the user includes or omits the trailing "/"